# How to access EJB3 deployed on TomEE (Plume) with Corba/IIOP client?

Tags: corba, apache-tomee, openejb, iiop, tomee-7

I am looking for some hint or possibly an example on exposing EJB3 as *IIOP/CORBA* compliant while deploying on *TomEE* (Plume) and accessing the same EJB3 with IIOP/CORBA client.

Our current application is designed as such that it’s *EJBs(EJB3)* are exposed to *CORBA/IIOP* clients and all our WEB and standalone clients are using those *EJBs* using *IIOP/CORBA* protocol.

Example:

```
Properties props= new Properties();
props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost","192.00.00.00");
props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort","3700");
initialContext= new InitialContext(props);
```

As *Glassfish* fully supports *corba* protocol and it works fine. Now, I want the same working with *TomEE* Plume.

Any inputs or help on the same will leads to us in deciding to select *TomEE* as the suitable candidate for our applications server in place of *Glassfish*.

Comment: Did you already have a look here?

http://openejb.apache.org/clients.html

Comment: I have already looked that link but the ways suggested is not according to  CORBA protocol. Refer my comment above for property for Glassfish, which clearly says that is specific to corba standard for host and port.

As far i know, I need to add geronimo-corba_3.0_spec-1.1.jar and need to add resource in 'tomee.xml' but not having any clue for next steps. i.e. what configuration required to deploy EJB as corba compliance and next is how to access using corba way using standalone java client.

Comment: In contrast to GlassFish TomEE is a Java EE WebProfile server.

Comment: Having said that it offers the EJB 3.1 lite specification which does not contain CORBA or RMI/IIOP respectively. If you want to access EJBs from remote I think the docs mentioned above should help. If you must use CORBA I think it doesn't work with TomEE.

Comment: Thanks for you inputs Robert.